# How to calculate joint pdf of two normals?

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

> Say $(X_1,X_2,X_3)^T \sim N_3\left(\pmatrix{3\\1\\4}, \pmatrix{6&1&-2\\1&13&4\\-2&4&4} \right)$.

> What is the joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ if $Y_1 = 2+X_1+X_2+X_3$, $Y_2 = 5+X_1-X_2+2X_3$?

Let $a=(1,1,1)$, then $Y_1 \sim N(2+a^T \mu,2+a^T\Sigma a) = N(10,31)$, right? Similarly then, we get $Y_2 \sim N(12,11)$.

The joint pdf is then given by

$$ f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi\times31\times11\times\sqrt{1-p^2}}\times\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-p^2)}\left[\left(\frac{y_1-10}{31}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_2-12}{11}\right)^2 -2p\left(\frac{y_1-10}{31}\right)\left(\frac{y_2-12}{11}\right)\right]\right)$$

Is this right? What would the correlation $p$ be? 0 because each $X_i$ are independent?

Comment: Those $X_i$ aren’t independent. Your first line gives a non-diagonal covariance matrix.

Comment: @Dave Then i guess i can't calculate $\rho$ and my work is ok then?

Comment: To obtain the joint distribution let $a = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1\\1&2}.$

Comment: @whuber And then $(Y_1,Y_2) \sim N(7 + a^T \mu, 7+ a^T \Sigma a)$ ? The + 2 and +5 confuse me here...

Comment: This requires the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @whuber said in the comments, a nice way to proceed is defining the matrix

$$a=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&-1\\1&2\end{array}\right]$$

Such that $(Y_1.Y_2)=(X_1,X_2,X_3)\cdot a+(2,5)$. Now, since this is a constant vector plus a linear transformation of a normally distributed vector, this also has normal distribution. Its mean is found to be $\mu=(2,5)+(3,1,4)\cdot a=(10,15)$. Its variance is given by $a^T\Sigma a=\left[\begin{array}{cc}29&-1\\-1&9\end{array}\right]$.

So, you have $\left[\begin{array}{c}Y_1\\Y_2\end{array}\right]\sim\mathcal N\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}10\\15\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{cc}29&-1\\-1&9\end{array}\right]\right)$.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would the correlation coefficient be $\rho_{Y_1,Y_2}=\frac{\text{cov}(Y_1,Y_2)}{\sigma_{Y_1}{\sigma_{Y_2}}} =\pmatrix{-\frac{1}{29\times 9}\\-\frac{1}{29\times 9}}$?

Comment: Yes, the correlation coefficient is -1/(29*9). It's not usually expressed as a vector though: usually you express it as a scalar (just the number -1/(29*9)) or a correlation matrix (which comes in handy when you have more than 2 variables).

Answer (score 1):

One way of finding the joint pdf of $Y = 2+X_1+X_2+X_3$ and $Z = 5+X_1-X_2+2X_3$ without matrix manipulations is to understand that since $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are *jointly normal*, *linear combinations* of $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are also *jointly normal*. Thus, all we need to do is find the means, variances, and covariance of $Y$ and $Z$ and we can write down an explicit formula for their joint pdf that doesn't involve matrices at all.

Do you know about the *linearity of expectation* and how to use this property to compute
\begin{align}
\mu_Y &= E[Y] = E[2+X_1+X_2+X_3]\\
\mu_Z &= E[Z] = E[5+X_1-X_2+2X_3]?
\end{align}

Do you know how to express the variance of a sum in terms of variances and covariances? That is, do you know how to calculate
\begin{align}
\sigma_Y^2 &= \operatorname{var}(2+X_1+X_2+X_3)\\
\sigma_Z^2 &= \operatorname{var}(5+X_1-X_2+2X_3)
\end{align}
in terms of $\sigma_i^2=\operatorname{var}(X_i), i=1,2,3$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_j), i, j = 1,2,3, i\neq j$?

Do you know that $\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)$ can be expressed in terms of $\sigma_i^2=\operatorname{var}(X_i), i=1,2,3$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_j), i, j = 1,2,3, i\neq j$ and this allows you to compute the correlation coefficient $\rho_{Y,Z}$?